# Best way to create a Wizard component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started learning React and I'm trying to create a Wizard component.
Originally I was picturing that it could be used like this:

```
<Wizard isVisible={this.state.isWizardVisible}>
    <Page1 />
    <Page2 />
</Wizard>
```

I started running into problems (still having an OOP mindset) when I wanted to extract properties, even components from the children (Page1, Page2) to configure/overwrite the Wizard (title, footer components, etc).

This of course can't be done, because on Wizard.render I don't have access to the components themselves.

Then I came across [this](https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/react-wizard) repo with a Wizard component. The component in the repo is configured with an array of Steps, which are javascript objects to configure the current step in the wizard and contain a component property which returns the React component.

That approach certainly solves the problem but I'm wondering if it could be done differently or if there's a more "React" way of solving it, in a way that each Page/Step component encapsulates the behavior and not the other way around (like in the repo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "React" way of solving it is to keep your whole application state at the very top of your component hierarchy. Of course, React is essentially just the V in MVC, and not opinionated when it comes to how you manage your data and state logic. But what you want to achieve is something like this:

```
<Wizard isVisible={this.state.isWizardVisible}>
    <GenericPage foo={something} bar={somethingElse} />
</Wizard>
```

By this logic, Wizard has access to all the application state you wish to provide, and pass down whatever GenericPage needs to render the current page. If you need a GenericPage component to be able to modify state, just pass down functions as props as well.

There are several frameworks that implement common ways to handle changes in the application state. Facebook has Flux, but Redux seems to push all the right buttons and is my framework of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the idea of having the parent have all the information, but in my case I want to influence the parent's title for example based on the current page. I know this would invert the flow of information which against that philosophy, but I'm not seeing any solutions at the moment

Comment: If you really have to, use the parent/ancestor component's local state to store some value. Also, in the parent/ancestor component, you have a function that mutates this state. Pass this function as a prop to the children, and simply call it from them when needed. Another thing, try to keep this pattern at a minimum to save you a few headaches: `<CustomComponent><Child /></CustomComponent>`. Leveraging the rendering of Child to CustomComponent's render function is a tidier approach in the long run.

Comment: This fiddle might help to explain what I'm trying to say: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/627ofoqo/ It's a very, very simplified take on the normal data flow pattern. All components potentially have access to everything in the app, and if you need to change something from anywhere, just call changeStore().

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and fiddle. 
It gave me a nice starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try memoizing the props with:

https://github.com/gilbox/react-derive

then you can pass the props from Page1 to Page2 component.

Comment: This may work, but giving it a quick scan it's a bit over my head. I will need to research it with a bit more detail.